# Wordpress not showing menu options in admin

Tags: wordpress

I started working on a wordpress page that was not finished by the previous developer, the problem is that when i open the page, it show every post like this

```
[mk_page_section bg_image=”http://ladietamigliore.it/wp- content/uploads/2016/04/adriani_magro.jpg” bg_position=”center center” bg_stretch=”true” min_height=”600″ sidebar=”sidebar-1″][vc_column][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner][vc_empty_space height=”120px”][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width=”1/2″][vc_images_carousel images=”446,447,448,449,450″ img_size=”full” onclick=”link_no” mode=”vertical” autoplay=”yes” hide_pagination_control=”yes” wrap=”yes”][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width=”1/2″][mk_padding_divider size=”200″ visibility=”hidden-sm”][vc_column_text]
```

i think that a plugins is not installed or that an update is missing, so i go to the wp-admin and it look like this [image]

there is not option for post or anything, whats wrong? how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that user doesn't have any admin rights - a "real" admin would have to change your user "role" in the user profile in order to give you access to all admin actions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user is not an Administrator, you can check this by going to /wp-admin/users.php and looking at the 'Role' column. If you have access to the Db you can run the below SQL query for updating an user role as administrator. Here I’m assuming user id as 2.

[sql] UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value=’a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}’ WHERE user_id=2 AND meta_key=’wp_capabilities’
[/sql]

Answer (score 0):

your and not getting all option because you are account don't Administration access. so you have to get administration access